# Spring cloud gateway not able to find the service recource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb7mb.png)

This is the spring boot application which is using java version 17, spring version 3.2.3 and cloud version 4.1.0 .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V53q.png)

This is my yaml file, where i configured the gateway to redirect the incoming url to product-service which is running on the port 8081.

Its throwing EFO exception when i hit apigateway for the first time and then shows no resource found.
Below is the error trace:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]

2024-03-05T11:38:50.138+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.a.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl     : Loading persistent provider registrations from [/tmp/tomcat.8080.4975531152331994569/conf/jaspic-providers.xml]
2024-03-05T11:38:50.141+05:30  INFO 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-05T11:38:50.141+05:30  INFO 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-05T11:38:50.141+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected GatewayMvcMultipartResolver
2024-03-05T11:38:50.141+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2024-03-05T11:38:50.141+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-03-05T11:38:50.142+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@7f55c883
2024-03-05T11:38:50.142+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@bf25b7c
2024-03-05T11:38:50.143+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-03-05T11:38:50.143+05:30  INFO 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-03-05T11:38:50.152+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/product/65e371cdfa0ece7c15e6ee75", parameters={}
2024-03-05T11:38:50.173+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2024-03-05T11:38:50.184+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2024-03-05T11:38:50.188+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/product/65e371cdfa0ece7c15e6ee75.]
2024-03-05T11:38:50.190+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2024-03-05T11:38:50.201+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2024-03-05T11:38:50.206+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-03-05T11:38:50.241+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-03-05T11:38:50.243+05:30 DEBUG 7851 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Mar 05 11:38:50 IST 2024, status=404, error=Not Found, path=/api/product/65e371cdfa0e
```

It should call the product service which is up and running. It is also registered with the DiscoveryServer.

Comment: please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on why you shouldn't add links to your code, and instead paste correctly formatted and only relevant code into the question

Comment: Please provide your dependencies, either pom.xml or build.gradle.